# Downloading images takes a lot of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I use the following method to download images:

```
                newlink = image.img['src']
                print('Downloading image', index)
                try:
                    response = requests.get(newlink, stream=True)
                    sleep(1)
                    with open(image_path, 'wb') as file:
                        sleep(1)
                        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, file)
                except Exception as e:

                    print(e)
                    print('Could not download image number ', index)
```

Everything works well, but I have noticed that when I run the script everyday, after some days (5-7), it takes a lot of time to download each image. When this happened, I closed pycharm and restarted my PC. After that, it started working well again.

I would like to know if anyone knows why this happened.

Thank you

Comment: Why are u using `sleep`?

Comment: because some times, maybe of  poor internet connection, i get an error. Using sleep i avoid that

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: i don't get any error, the script is working well.The only issue is that after 5-6 day running the same script, it takes a lot of time to download the image. I should restart to fix that and i am weird why this may happen. Think about that it download image in 2 seconds and when the issue appear, it takes 1-2 minutes to download one simple image

Answer (score 0):

This might be a memory or network stack issue. According to the documentation:
`http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/`

If you set stream to True when making a request, Requests cannot release the connection back to the pool unless you consume all the data or call Response.close. This can lead to inefficiency with connections. If you find yourself partially reading request bodies (or not reading them at all) while using stream=True, you should make the request within a with statement to ensure it’s always closed:

```
with requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', stream=True) as r:
    # Do things with the response here.
```

Give this a try:

```
newlink = image.img['src']
print('Downloading image', index)
try:
    with requests.get(newlink, stream=True) as response:
        sleep(1)
        with open(image_path, 'wb') as file:
            sleep(1)
            shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, file)
except Exception as e:

    print(e)
    print('Could not download image number ', index)
```

Comment: Yes, i through that may be memory issue. The solution work for me.Thank you